# How to concurrently read and update a field of mongodb from java

Tags: java, mongodb

Let's take an example of facebook posts where multiple users give likes to a post. Now for some post currently database stores 10 likes and if two users liked that post concurrently then both will read 10 as current like and update 11 one by one but the correct value should be 12. How to achieve this using mongodb and java.

Answer (score 2):

Check the operator [$inc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/).

Here is a sample code from this [link](http://sysgears.com/articles/atomic-value-increment-in-mongodb-using-java-driver/):

```
// connect to MongoDB server.
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
DB database = mongo.getDB("mydb");
DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("testCollection");

// create a simple db object where counter value is 0
DBObject temp = new BasicDBObject("name", "someName").append("counter", 0);

// insert it into the collection
collection.insert(temp);

// create an increment query
DBObject modifier = new BasicDBObject("counter", 1);
DBObject incQuery = new BasicDBObject("$inc", modifier);

// create a search query
DBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject("name", "someName");

// increment a counter value atomically
WriteResult upRes = collection.update(searchQuery, incQuery);
```

Comment: Yes. that will work if i want to increment but my problem is that two concurrent threads are reading same value from database and then changing that value (doing some manipulation) and then updating that value to database. for example.. A and B are two users. A reads 10 and B reads 10 concurrently and A do some calculation on 10 and update first then B then B should read the updated value.

Comment: Then, assuming user A is reading and modifying a record. How do you expect to handle user B? You can either lock the record and throw an exception stating it is being used, or wait for a transaction / lock to end.